can receive echo while continous send
I am trying to send a can data and at the same time trying to receive data. But even though I am not going to receive any data still some random echo data is continuously coming, but when I comment the

send_can_message(bus)

the echo receive is not happening.
following is the code
import can
import time

def check_can_device():
    try:
        # Create a bus instance using 'pcan' interface
        bus = can.Bus(interface='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=250000)
        print("CAN device is present and connected.")
        return bus
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"CAN device is not present or not connected. Error: {e}")
        return None

def send_can_message(bus):
    if bus is not None:
        try:
            # Create a CAN message
            message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x01, data=[0x00], is_extended_id=False)
            # Send the message on the CAN bus
            bus.send(message)
            print(f"Message sent: {message}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending CAN message: {e}")

def read_can_messages(bus):
    if bus is not None:
        try:
            # Read a message from the CAN bus
            message = bus.recv(timeout=10.0)  # Timeout in seconds
            if message:
                print(f"Message received: {message}")
            else:
                print("No message received within the timeout period.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading CAN message: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bus = check_can_device()
    #send_can_message(bus)
    while True:
        send_can_message(bus)
        read_can_messages(bus)
        time.sleep(2)
        

output when I remove the send_can_message(bus) in while loop
> Python 3.12.7 (tags/v3.12.7:0b05ead, Oct  1 2024, 03:06:41) [MSC v.1941 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
= RESTART: C:\Users\Saidevaraj Manoharan\Projects\UMC\Python\Sample GUI\candevice.py

CAN device is present and connected. 
No message received within the timeout period.
No message received within the timeout period.

output when I add the send_can_message(bus) in while loop
> = RESTART: C:\Users\Saidevaraj Manoharan\Projects\UMC\Python\Sample GUI\candevice.py
CAN device is present and connected.
Message sent: Timestamp:        0.000000    ID:      001    S Rx                DL:  1    00
Message received: Timestamp: 1730223958.407297    ID:      008    S Rx E              DL:  4    00 19 00 08
Message sent: Timestamp:        0.000000    ID:      001    S Rx                DL:  1    00
Message received: Timestamp: 1730223958.407553    ID:      008    S Rx E              DL:  4    00 19 00 10
Message sent: Timestamp:        0.000000    ID:      001    S Rx                DL:  1    00
Message received: Timestamp: 1730223958.407809    ID:      008    S Rx E              DL:  4    00 19 00 18
Message sent: Timestamp:        0.000000    ID:      001    S Rx                DL:  1    00
Message received: Timestamp: 1730223958.408108    ID:      008    S Rx E              DL:  4    00 19 00 20

what could be the cause and how to resolve this.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode
